# How to check whether a cell contains a number of search words

Tags: excel

I am looking for answer on how to use correctly the "FIND"formula or any other formula that can help me finding string on one cell to another.

```
I use the find formula to find these:
=IF(FIND(A1,B1),"yes","no")
Col1 - Col2
A,B - A,B,C = formula works well
A,C - A,B,C = formula not working. Returning "#VALUE"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your expected result instead of `#VALUE!`? If you just want to eliminate it, you can use `ISERROR` to handle error values. Otherwise, if your expected value is still `YES` since *A* and *C* are found in the text, you will have to use another way of writing your formula.

Comment: I want to have the result of yes also, because there's A,C in the Array.

Comment: Are you okay with VBA solution using UDF?

Answer (score 1):

FIND only checks if the full String from Col1 is contained in Col2.
if you want to check for all items, you would have to split the String by commas somehow.

Comment: Is there a way that I can split the string without adding new column? I mean, splitting only using formulas.

Answer (score 1):

If your okay with using VBA, above can be achieved using function, you can use following code as UDF.

```
Function FindExistence(firstStr As String, secStr As String) As String
    Dim firstArr() As String, secArr() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim fElem As Variant, sElem As Variant
    Dim isExist As Boolean

    firstArr = Split(firstStr, ",") 'comma separated values of first cell into array
    secArr = Split(secStr, ",")     'comma separated values of second cell into array
    For Each fElem In firstArr      'loop through each element in array of first array
        isExist = False             'set boolean variable to False
        For Each sElem In secArr    'loop through each element in array of second array
            If fElem = sElem Then   'check if elements in both array are equal
                isExist = True      'if elements are equal exit loop, check next element
                Exit For
            End If
        Next sElem
        If Not isExist Then Exit For 'if isExist is false exit all loop
    Next fElem
    If Not isExist Then             'if isExist is false return No else Yes
        FindExistence = "No"
    Else
        FindExistence = "Yes"
    End If
End Function
```

See image for reference.

[image]

On how to create function see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f).

Instead of using two `Exit For` you can also use [`GoTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/goto-statement).

Answer (score 1):

This is a quirky alternative to the above presented UDF approach, if you can accept limitations to keeping the "relative distance" between the pattern and function cells involved. My approach involves defining Names for predefined formulas (containing relative cell references).

In the following sample code I assume that I want to use the find formula in cell `C2` and my comma separated pattern is stored in the neighbouring cell left to it (relative!).

Now I can define the following "names" (press <cntrl> <F3>).

```
one:    =LEFT(Sheet1!B2;FIND(",";Sheet1!B2)-1)
oneR:   =MID(Sheet1!B2;FIND(",";Sheet1!B2)+1;LEN(Sheet1!B3))
two:    =LEFT(oneR;FIND(",";oneR & ",")-1)
three:  =MID(oneR;FIND(",";oneR & ",")+1;LEN(oneR))
```

You can extend the sample if you are interested in more than three parts. In the formula cell (`C2`, always the one directly to the right of the pattern cell) I can now write

```
=IFERROR(AND(FIND(one;D2);FIND(two;D2);FIND(three;D2));0;1)
```

to check whether all three words of the pattern occur in the target cell string (`D2`). The result is `1` if all three patterns are found, otherwise it returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *no-column-helper* approach and guaranteed zero VBA.
I use an *array formula* as shown below:

```
= LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))
= SUM(
    --ISNUMBER(
               MATCH(
                     MID(
                         SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),
                         ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")))),
                         1),
                     MID(
                         SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""),
                         ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","")))),
                         1),
                     0)
               )
      )
```

**How does it work?**

- First, we need a way to get all the characters in your string to an array so that we can check it one by one for matches. We do that using the formula:

  ```
  MID(
      SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),
      ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")))),
      1)
  ```

  General logic is `MID(<text>,<start_num>,<num_chars>)` where instead of assigning one numerical value in `<start_num>`, we assign an array of numbers using `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))))`. In a straightforward form, that is `ROW([reference])` (e.g. `ROW(1:10)` gives us array of numbers 1 to 10, an array with 10 elements). But to make this formula work, we need to make sure that the size of our array is equal to the number of characters we are working on excluding `,` commas. So we eliminate the comma first by using `SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")` and get the length of the resulting string in memory. For example if you have text **A,C** in cell `A2` then `SUBSTITUTE` function will yield **`AC`** (in memory) and getting the length of that using `LEN` returns 2. Then we use that returned value as boundary for our array. We simply concatenate it with `"1:"` and to make it return a valid reference, we use `INDIRECT` function.
- We repeat above for the string we search for matches (e.g. cell `B2` contains **A,B,C**, we need to put that in an array too)
- Conduct search using `MATCH` function. Here, we use the array of values we have generated using the 2 steps above. `MATCH(<lookup_value>,<lookup_array>,[match_type])` is the general form. Fortunately, we can also use an array of values for `<lookup_value>` argument instead of a single value. So we use the array we yield in step 1 above as our *lookup_values*.
- Next is we confirm how many matches we have using `ISNUMBER`. `MATCH` function returns a numerical value (which is the position of the matched value in the array) so we simply evaluate that using `ISNUMBER`. This returns an array of Boolean values `{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}` <s>but since we need to count it somehow, we use double negation</s> `--` <s>to convert it to numbers which yields `{1,0,1}`.</s>
- Final step is just use `SUM` function to count the number of matches and compare it to the length of the search string without the commas. We confirm the formula using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>
- Alternatively, you can use an `AND` function in the final step to check if all matches are found.

**Edit1:** Formula using `AND` to directly evaluate if all matches are found.

```
= AND(
      ISNUMBER(
               MATCH(
                     MID(
                         SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""),
                         ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")))),
                         1),
                     MID(
                         SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""),
                         ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","")))),
                         1),
                     0)
               )
      )
```

So this will return `TRUE` if all characters in cell `A2` is found in all character set in cell `B2`. Now this works for uniform comma separated strings only (e.g **`A,K,E,G`** to be searched in **`A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K`**). This will fail on non-uniform comma separated strings (e.g. **`A,BC,D,EFG,H,I,J`** then trying to find **`BC,I`**). I hope this gets you going.